# Android Toast before Intent onNewIntent

Tags: java, android

I'm blocking for several hours on it, is  there a chance to toast prior to performing the intent? With this code, the toast appears only after the execution.

```
    @Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    resolveIntent(intent);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I mean technically you could make another Intent inside of that. Basically ans intern "onCreate" if you know what I mean?

```
    @Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        @Override
    public void onNewIntentCreate(...) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    onNewIntentCreate();
    resolveIntent(intent);
}
```

Or something similar. Could that work for you?

Comment: Thank you, however could you detail how you implement nested method in Java?

Comment: I just wrote it and it kinda just worked for me. I used another nested method (maybe without the Override)  with different conditions/demands though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use handler for it

```
   @Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }
   }, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

 }
```

Comment: The app closes with the finish().

Comment: @GwenaelDelaleux sry. U can remove finish() and try it agin

Comment: The toast only appears after the intent is finished.